# Error 404 when loading a .geojson file in a web application (leaflet, ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, gis, geojson

I'm learning how to build GIS web applications, and I'm getting an HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found trying to load a geojson file into a map built with leaflet. I'w checking the map directly online in my website

In  I have inserted this tag that calls the AJAX file:

The script is:

```
 var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('/.../data/attractions.geojson', {pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                var str = "<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4><hr>";
                str += "<a href='"+feature.properties.web+"' target='blank'>";
                str += "<img src='img/"+feature.properties.image+"' width='200px'>";
                str += "</a>";
                return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(str);
            }});
 geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

Everything is right, but I read this error loading my geojson.

I think the problem is with the geojson file extension, but I don't know how I can handle it. I use a windows hosting through Aruba. The file is not damaged (I tried to open it on Qgis without problems)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem, I hope to help someone to save time since I lost hours today.

Basically, you just need to replace ".geojson" with ".json" (without changing the file extension).

I do not understand why, and if you have the answer please let me now, but now it works.

Comment: This [L.GeoJSON.AJAX](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) library is very old and is no longer being developed. Consider using `$.getJSON` from `jquery`, `axios` or even plain `featch` if you don't need to support old browsers like IE.